# how to handle multiple full screen images in android. : Memory concern

Tags: android, image, audio

I need to handle around 120 images and 120 audio files in my project.i placed all images in drawable and audio files in raw folder, Images should change by clicking button or fling gesture and same time corresponding short audio file should play.

Which of the following is the right way to handle images?

1.Can i use imageview to show the image and change its src each time

2.Can i use imageSwitcher

3.or any other technique?

And

What about memory(To handle 120 images and audio files)?

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you try [ViewFlipper](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-viewflipper-example). You can even add gesture detection to it. It will satisfy what you are looking for.

Comment: PLz go through the link. ImageView and ViewFlipper are both different. You need not use ImageView if you use ViewFlipper.

Comment: where i can display images then?

Comment: Well actually you can display images in viewflipper

Comment: Take a look at this http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-viewflipper-and-slidingdrawer.html